# how to sum coulmn wise if number of data is not same in every column?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am using this awk script to calculate the average of every column. This script is working fine if data points are same in each column.If some one can help me in modifying this script.
Data points in column are like ( sample file but actual file contains 10000 coulmns):

```
1 3 4 5   
2 3 5 6  
5 4 5 6  
6 6 6  
7 7  
8
```

```awk
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[i]+=$i
        if($i!="")
            b[i]++}
    }
END {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", a[i]/b[i], (i==NF?ORS:OFS)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `NF` which, by the time you get to the last input line, is only 1. You need to iterate over the length of your calculating arrays.

Also looking at your whitespace delimited data structure, you can never have an empty variable, so there is no need for the `if` test either

```
awk '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[i]+=$i; b[i]++
    }
END {
    for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++)      #<-----iterate over length(a) not NF
        printf "%s%s", a[i]/b[i], (i==length(a)?ORS:OFS)
}' file
```

As per @kusalananda comment, if your `awk` version does not support determining the length of an array in this way then you will need to find the max number of fields during input ....

```
awk '{max = (max < NF) ? NF : max;
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[i]+=$i; b[i]++}
    }
END {
    for(i=1; i<=max; i++)
        printf "%s%s", a[i]/b[i], (i==max?ORS:OFS)
}' file
```

Comment: The `length()` functions gives the length in number of characters of its string argument. To use it on arrays, you have to assume that your `awk` supports that as an extension (GNU `awk` does).

Comment: Which apparently mine does. Thanks for the heads up.